# The argument type 'int' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Expression<int, IntType>'

Tags: sqlite, datetime, flutter, dart, flutter-moor

I'm using [moor_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/moor_flutter) package to interact with sqlite database on flutter app. I'm trying to parse tomorrow as in number of the day in a month. For example the date today is `24`, therefore I'm parsing `25` as tomorrow inside the moor_flutter's `isSmallerOrEqual()` method. The purpose is to parse 25 as in `runtimetype **Expression<int, IntType>**` but I'm parsing it as `runtimetype **int**`, This is because I don't know how to convert `int` to `Expression<int, IntType>`. I've tried some different approaches but non of them are succeeding.

Below is the function where I'm doing this.

```dart
Future NearDueDate() {
    // final DateTime currentDate = new DateTime.now();
    var dayToday = currentDate.day;
    var tommorow = int.parse(dayToday.toString()) + 1;
    return (select(the_records)
          ..where((t_r) => t_r.due_date.day.isSmallerOrEqual(tommorow)))
        .get();
  }
```

**Note** the problem here is how can I convert `int` to `Expression<int, IntType>` so that I don't get any error on `t_r.due_date.day.isSmallerOrEqual(tommorow)`?

Thank you, posted with Love.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't comment this answer.

If `Expression` is some kind of model. You would have to convert it by creating an instance of `Expression`.

Take this for example:

We have a model, `User`

```
class User {

    int _id;
    String _name;

    User(this._name);

    User.withId(this._id, this._name );

    int get id => _id;

    String get name => _name;

    set name(String newName) {
        if (newName.length <= 255) {
            this._name = newName;
        }
    }

    // Convert a User object into a Map object
    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {

        var map = Map<String, dynamic>();
        if (id != null) {
            map['id'] = _id;
        }
        map['name'] = _name;

        return map;
    }

    // Extract a User object from a Map object
    User.fromMapObject(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
        this._id = map['id'];
        this._name = map['name'];
    }
}
```

#### So this is the main point here

To create a type of `User` we would do something like this

```
user = User('John');
```

Now the type of `user.name` would be `User<String>`

Regularly, `'John'` would just be a string. Now that it is part of the User class. It is `User<String>`